# In Gmail's Inbox, is there a way to know if I received a message as a 'To' or as a 'CC'?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

When one looks at the listing of one's [Gmail inbox,](https://mail.google.com/mail) is there a way to distinguish only messages that were sent to the inbox as a **To:**, and not as **CC:** or **BCC:**?

Answer (score 2):

You can do search like:

```
to:me
```




```
cc:me
```




```
bcc:me
```

[image: 0]